# How to call the df from a callback in dash

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a dash dashbboard

I use a callback to retrieve my data as a table

```
@app.callback(
    Output('kpi_id', 'children'),
    [Input(component_id='my_button')]
)
def create_kpi(value):
    df= df.loc[df['user_role'].isin(value)]
    df_kpi_users = kpi(df)
    data = df_kpi_users.to_dict("records")
    return data
```

I use a list of names to declare the names of my columns

```
TABLE_COLUMNS = ['day', 'DAU', 'DAU_7']
```

Inside the html declaration I have:

```
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='kpi_id',
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in TABLE_COLUMNS],
```

My problem is: if I need to call the new table as a df to apply a certain conditional formatting, like the data_bars, all the examples I find is to call the df like this:

```
style_data_conditional=(
        data_bars(df, 'DAU')
    )
```

But I don't have a df declared, so how can I call my table?

Comment: It's not clear where your dataframe is coming from in the first place. Your callback `Input` is incomplete (has an id, but is missing a prop). Is there a reason you can't use the same callback to update the styling, too?

Comment: How could I update the styling with the callback?

Comment: Make that another output of your callback.